# Trouble with Heroku SSL Endpoint

Tags: ssl, heroku, openssl

I am trying to add an SSL cert to Heroku. The cert was purchased from Network Solutions. I went through all of the steps and created a .csr file, uploaded that file to NetworkSolutions, downloaded their bundle of .crt files (MYSITE.crt, AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt, NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA.crt) and then combined the site cert & the intermediate certificate (AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt) bundles. When I try and add the final.crt file I produce to Heroku I get:

```
!    Expires at can't be blank
!    Pem is invalid
```

Using Preview I can clearly see that "Not Valid After" is set so I am not really sure what is going on here.

For what its worth I also tried combining NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA.crt with MYSITE.CRT & also combining all 3. All with no luck.

This kind of thing isn't my strong point (I am sure you can tell) so its very possible I am missing something but if you have any ideas on what it might be I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue. Posting what worked for you would be a big help. Thanks

Comment: No i haven't, I ended up going on to work on something else and figured i'd get back to it. did you find a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced the same problem today.

Below are the steps I followed to fix it.

1. Combine the certificate files in the below order (from the site
   certificate to root certificate) into a .crt or .pem file. Lets assume you name it `Mysite_combined.crt`.

   MySite.crt, NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA.crt, AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
2. Open Mysite_combined.crt the content of the file will look like

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   ..
   -----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   ..
   -----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   ```

Now, Insert line feed between each certificate. Make sure there is no white space or blank line in the edited file. The content should now look like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
..
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
..
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

1. Now add the certificate to Heroku using the command

   heroku certs:add Mysite_combined.crt Mysite.key

**Note:** Since Network solution certificate does not have a pass code, you can ignore the steps to remove pass code in heroku site. If you use a key which has pass code refer to [this article](http://blog.matthodan.com/how-to-setup-heroku-hostname-ssl-with-godaddy) which details how to setup the SSL for heroku. You should do the step 2 above in any case.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Would be nice for Heroku updates its documentation!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just spent 2 hours battling the same problem. Line feed between the certs in the combined file was the key! +1 for updating Heroku docs.

Comment: FYI When you combine the two files, using .crt might be safer that .pem althoufgh as you mentioned it SHOUDL work either way.... when I tried .pem heroku barfed, but when I used .crt it worked. It was the exact same file since I just copied the .pem to a new .crt filename.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely their was an error in cat'ing your cert together with the intermediate. You should look to see that there was not a missing line break, or extra line breaks that may have caused the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, not the case. From what I read that seemed to be the most common issues but this seems to run a bit deeper. I spent too many hours trying to figure it out yesterday so going to try and start from scratch this weekend. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and in my case it turned out to be the order of the arguments. Apparently the heroku utility expects the .crt file to precede the .key file.

In other words:`heroku certs:add server.crt server.key`

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, I had to add a newline at the end of my site.crt before running this command:

```
$ cat site.crt ca_bundle.pem > final.crt
```