# Heroku SSL Endpoint, "Expires can't be blank Pem is Invalid"

Tags: ssl, heroku

I am attempting to upload a dreamhost SSL cert top heroku. I am following this guide http://blog.yodersolutions.com/using-dreamhost-for-herokus-ssl-cert/ right now.

Which gave me an invalid certificate error.

I removed the newlines at the end of the certificate body. Which gave me this error:

```
Adding SSL Endpoint to domain... failed
 !    Expires at can't be blank
 !    Pem is invalid
```

I tried using the https://github.com/heroku/heroku-ssl-doctor but that gave me Internal Server error. Is there anything I can do?

I am having a very similar issue to this [Trouble with Heroku SSL Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125587/trouble-with-heroku-ssl-endpoint) issue but the proposed solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the server.crt. Check that

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

are properly separated, when concatenate they tend to overlap like so.

```
  -----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

And this causes a problem.