# Adding an SSL Cert on heroku with network solution

Tags: ssl, heroku, openssl

I am trying to add an SSL cert to Heroku. The cert was purchased from Network Solutions. 
I didn't create myself .csr file, they did it.

NetworkSolutions, downloaded their bundle of .crt files

- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- NetworkSolutions_CA.crt
- UTNAddTrustServer_CA.crt
- WWW.mydomain.COM.crt

I have tried to follow this tutorial

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

I have combined crt files like here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125587/trouble-with-heroku-ssl-endpoint?answertab=votes#tab-top )

If i don't have any key file. Can generate a key file from crt file ?

Bolo

Comment: No, you can't generate a key from a certificate. If that were possible, it would totally undermine the entire public-key infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you. You have confirmed what I thought

Comment: @Bolo how did you solved it? (not having a key file)

Comment: Checkout the answer on stackoverlow [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125587/trouble-with-heroku-ssl-endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125587/trouble-with-heroku-ssl-endpoint)